# Custom Off-topic Close reasons

Tags: discussion, site-guidelines

As a follow up to the [Help Center](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help) [post](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/faq-scope-definition-help-center-on-topic-and-off-topic), and with a shiny round of mods just around the corner, we should probably be looking at [custom close reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) to add into the closing/flagging views (at current, we can only define "other" due to having nothing there yet).
While we haven't been going for a particularly long time, we can still define these as such:

- Taking closed, off-topic posts and using them as a basis for close reasons
- Taking input from the off-topic close reason "Other"
- Using what we defined in [this post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help).
- Your input - anything you find wouldn't fit into our question scope, but is likely to be asked.

Answer (score 4):

A common reason for close I've been seeing is the following:

> Questions about **site or resource recommendations**  are off-topic because they are largely opinionated and attract polling, opinion-based answers and spam. Ask a **specific question**, not a poll.

Comment: Feel free to edit away; it's community wiki.

Comment: Would that not go under the last two close reasons on the regular Close dialog?

Comment: @CanadianLuke yes, but I was thinking more along the lines of making it abundantly clear that it's not welcome here with a specific reason

Comment: Understood :)&nbsp;

Comment: Just to bump this, [this](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3064/9) question, asked today, would fall under this close reason.

Answer (score 3):

> Questions about Freelancing Website services for finding or using clients are off topic, as we are not the website's support channel. They have policies that dictate how they run. For more information, see `[here](some-link)`.

Comment: We went ahead and added this in. Members of our community can now use this close reason to close support-related questions not applicable to freelancing problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Questions asking for or requesting work are considered off-topic, since we are a site to ask questions that freelancers face day-to-day. For more information, see `[here](http://example.com)`

Questions that would be off-topic for this reason:

- https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/2608/9

Comment: I would try rewording this, actually, as there seems to be a rise in people assuming we're oDesk as of late and having a specific close reason for that would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I definitely agree, @Amelia! I know there's already a meta topic about it [here](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/221/9), that should be worth investigating

Answer (score 1):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a Freelance Website service are considered off-topic as they may attract opinionated answers and spam. For more information, see here.

Question(s) that would be considered off-topic for this reason:

- [Freelance site with lowest commission fees?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3030/9)
- https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3058/9