# New Off Topic reason - Advertising for Jobs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

I am seeing a few people posting for Job Opportunities within the community, which is not what we're about. I'd like to get some community/mod feedback on a new custom close reason. Feel free to add a new answer with the wording and links you would like to see when we close these types of questions. As well, should we make a specific Meta post about *why* it is off topic?

> Questions asking for freelancers to complete work are off-topic because it is essentially advertising, not asking answerable questions. If you need workers, you can check out [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).  For more information, see [the Help Center](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: What would the timeline be like to implement this off-topic reason?

Comment: @Chris just need 2 mods to sign in and hit approve

Comment: So you and either Amelia or jmort253?

Comment: Yup. And for more than just 2 votes

Answer (score 4):

To ease the need to write a meta post, we could link the close reason directly to the [help center page on user behavior](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). See the following section:

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

Comment: Can we edit that section to include asking people here for jobs?

Comment: We can't edit it, but I can ask the community management team if it's worth adding that into the global template for all sites.  I'll do that right now.

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from my [related answer](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/216/9):

> Questions asking for or requesting work are considered off-topic since they are essentially advertising. For more information, see "[Why can't I ask for freelancers to work on my project?](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/9)" or "[Why can't I advertise for work?](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/9)"

I think it would be a good idea to create a meta post for these scenarios.